# Using GPO to configure Automatic Update

Tags: windows-server-essentials

What I'm trying to do is configure automatic updates via server for all clients on network which I have set for every Saturday at 1800 with an auto retsart in 15 mins after the updates have completed.

However, my concern is that if windows update is turned on individually on local PC's can they still run updates whenever and if so is there a way to disable that?? And force them to only update at the time the GPO stipulates and not any other time. Or does GPO take precedence no matter what setting local clients have??

Does that make sense??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these clients are joined to the AD domain then the Windows Updates settings from your GPO will be applied to the client machines. The client machines will not have "their own" Windows Updates settings.

Additionally, you may want to disable access to Windows Updates in your GPO if you want to prevent users from manually checking for and installing updates.

Comment: My question was poorly worded I think. What I was getting at was the second part of your answer. Thats what I needed to know. Where would I find that setting within Group Policy?

Comment: I'm guessing USer Config >.........Windows Config > Windows Update > Remove Access to use all Windows Update features ??

Comment: Yes............